# deploy mvc 5 to azure websites error InvalidOperationException: UserId not found

Tags: azure

The site works fine using local database & vs2013 express. When I deploy to azure website using the free website and SQL server I get this error. When trying any view that uses the database an InvalidOperationException: UserId not found exception is thrown.

I have removed all the `[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]` attributes from my controllers and deployed again and still have the same error.

Tried the _AppStart.cshtml code

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "User", "Id",
                                             "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
}
```

still get the same error after re-deploy, I can use MS SQL manager to connect to the database and run query's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the problem is with the code above autoCreateTables creating different identity membership tables. Deleted the database and removed the code above. Now I have to fix the InRole bug with Azure.